# How to refer a variable to the child component with React?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Main extends Component{

   /*Skip function and constructor...*/

   var previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia;
    previewContainer.appendChild("<div>Test</div>");

  /*Skip some code...*/


    render() {

        return (

            <div className="container my-4">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div>Screen section</div>
                        <div className="screen_section">
                            {this.state.showMyScreen ? <MyScreen localMediaAvailable={this.state.localMediaAvailable} /> : null  }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


}



    class MyScreen extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        render() {

            let showLocalTrack = this.props.localMediaAvailable ? (
                <div className="flex-item"><div ref="localMedia" style={{height:320, width:640}} /> </div>) : '';   

            return (
                <div>
                    <div>My Screen</div>
                    {showLocalTrack}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

I write some react code as above, and I have an error message of fail to appendChild of undefined, the problem is I cannot refer the variable with        `var previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia;`
Is it possible to have any method to solve this problem? Or instead of serate them into two component, I should write them in one instead?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: actually, my code will append a video stream with the appendChild. However, it has an error of undefined in "var previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia", the variable cannot refer to the div element. So, the problem is I cannot refer the localMedia div element.

Comment: Will this work **var previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia;** ? you have to remove **var**, this will work **previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia;**

Comment: Yes, it works. I just skip some of the lines of code, as var previewContainer = this.refs.localMedia; is inside a function.I tried to write it with one class before, and it workfs correctly, but when I seperate it into two class with parent and child. The error occur.